# Binance futures UserData Stream via Websocket Problem

Tags: python

Actually I am Using Binance futures User Data Stream for Cancelling the orders. But Some of my Orders are not Canceled. I Made a Code that Cancels the SL when My Tp hits and it Cancels the TP when my Sl hits.But Now Some of my Sl's and Tp's are not canceled even my TP or SL gets hit.

## This is the Code that i Used....

```
import datetime
import json
import threading
import requests
import websocket
import sys
import ccxt
import random
from binance.client import Client

Api = 'None'
Secret = 'None'

BinanceFutures = ccxt.binance({'apiKey': Api,'secret': Secret,'enableRateLimit': True,'options': {'defaultType': 'future','defaultMarket':'futures'}})
BinanceFutures.load_markets()

client = Client(Api,Secret)

SummarySavingList = []
ProblemsSavingList = []
def ProblemSaver():
    ProblemsSavedList = []
    while True:
        for Problem in ProblemsSavingList:
            if not Problem in ProblemsSavedList:
                Symbol = Problem.split(',')[0].split(":")[1]
                ProblemName = Problem.split(',')[1].split(":")[1]
                Where = Problem.split(',')[2].split(":")[1]
                restorePoint = sys.stdout
                sys.stdout = sys.stdout
                sys.stdout = open(f"C:\\Users\\mujah\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\RobotTrials\\Problems.txt","a")
                print(f"Message:{ProblemName} from {Where} when running functions on {Symbol}......")
                sys.stdout.close()
                sys.stdout = restorePoint
                ProblemsSavedList.append(Problem)
def PositionCloser(Coin):
    try:
        PositionInfo = client.futures_position_information(symbol=Coin)
        if float(PositionInfo[0]['positionAmt']) != 0:
            SELL = client.futures_create_order(symbol=Coin,side='SELL',type='MARKET',quantity=abs(float(PositionInfo[0]['positionAmt'])))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
def SummarySaver():
    SummarySavedList = []
    while True:
        for Summary in SummarySavingList:
            if not Summary in SummarySavedList:
                Symbol = Summary.split(',')[0].split(":")[1]
                Side = Summary.split(',')[1].split(":")[1]
                Result = Summary.split(',')[2].split(":")[1]
                SellTiming = Summary.split(',')[3].split(":")[1]
                restorePoint = sys.stdout
                sys.stdout = sys.stdout
                sys.stdout = open(f"C:\\Users\\mujah\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\RobotTrials\\Summary.txt","a")
                print(f"{Result} Hit When {Side} Trade is Taken On {Symbol},It Was Sold on {SellTiming}...")
                sys.stdout.close()
                sys.stdout = restorePoint
                SummarySavedList.append(Summary)
def StartStreaming():
    try:
        BINANCE_FUTURES_END_POINT = "https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/listenKey"
        def create_futures_listen_key(api_key):
            response = requests.post(url=BINANCE_FUTURES_END_POINT, headers={'X-MBX-APIKEY': api_key})
            return response.json()['listenKey']
        FUTURES_STREAM_END_POINT_1 = "wss://fstream.binance.com"
        listen_key = create_futures_listen_key(Api)
        futures_connection_url = f"{FUTURES_STREAM_END_POINT_1}/ws/{listen_key}"
        listen_key = create_futures_listen_key(Api)
        url = f"{FUTURES_STREAM_END_POINT_1}/ws/{listen_key}"
        def on_open(ws):
            print(f"Open: futures order stream connected")
        def on_message(ws, message):
            message = json.loads(message)
            print(f"Message: {message}")
            if message["e"] == 'ORDER_TRADE_UPDATE':
                Symbol = message["o"]["s"]
                Type = message["o"]["o"]
                Status = message["o"]["x"]
                Side = message["o"]['S']
                if Status == 'FILLED' and Side == 'SELL':
                    if Type == 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET':
                        try:
                            Cancel = client.futures_cancel_all_open_orders(symbol=Symbol)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                        SellTiming = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
                        PositionCloser(Coin=Symbol)
                        SummarySavingList.append(f"Symbol:{Symbol},Side:LONG,Result:Takeprofit,SellTiming:{SellTiming}")
                    elif Type == 'STOP_MARKET' and Side == 'SELL':
                        try:
                            Cancel = client.futures_cancel_all_open_orders(symbol=Symbol)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                        SellTiming = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
                        PositionCloser(Coin=Symbol)
                        SummarySavingList.append(f"Symbol:{Symbol},Side:LONG,Result:StopLoss,SellTiming:{SellTiming}")
                elif Status == 'EXPIRED':
                    if Type == 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET' and Side == 'SELL':
                        try:
                            Cancel = client.futures_cancel_all_open_orders(symbol=Symbol)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                        SellTiming = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
                        PositionCloser(Coin=Symbol)
                        SummarySavingList.append(f"Symbol:{Symbol},Side:LONG,Result:TakeProfit,SellTiming:{SellTiming}")
                    elif Type == 'STOP_MARKET' and Side == 'SELL':
                        try:
                            Cancel = client.futures_cancel_all_open_orders(symbol=Symbol)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                        SellTiming = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
                        PositionCloser(Coin=Symbol)
                        SummarySavingList.append(f"Symbol:{Symbol},Side:LONG,Result:StopLoss,SellTiming:{SellTiming}")
                    elif Status == 'PARTIALLY_FILLED':
                        if Type == 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET' and Side == 'SELL':
                            try:
                                Cancel = client.futures_cancel_all_open_orders(symbol=Symbol)
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(e)
                            SellTiming = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
                            PositionCloser(Coin=Symbol)
                            SummarySavingList.append(
                                f"Symbol:{Symbol},Side:LONG,Result:TakeProfit,SellTiming:{SellTiming}")
                        elif Type == 'STOP_MARKET' and Side == 'SELL':
                            try:
                                Cancel = client.futures_cancel_all_open_orders(symbol=Symbol)
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(e)
                            SellTiming = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
                            PositionCloser(Coin=Symbol)
                            SummarySavingList.append(
                                f"Symbol:{Symbol},Side:LONG,Result:StopLoss,SellTiming:{SellTiming}")
        def on_error(ws, error):
            print(f"Error: {error}")
        def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
            print(f"Close: {close_status_code} {close_msg}")
        def stream_ticker():
            ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url=url,on_open=on_open,on_message=on_message,on_error=on_error,on_close=on_close)
            ws.run_forever()
        stream_ticker()
    except Exception as e:
        ProblemsSavingList.append(f"Symbol:None,Problem:{e},Where:Streamer,Number:{random.randint(1,1000)}")
        pass
SummaryThread = threading.Thread(target=SummarySaver)
SummaryThread.start()
ProblemThread = threading.Thread(target=ProblemSaver)
ProblemThread.start()
StartStreaming()
```

Will you please Check my Code. and say if anything iam doing wrong.Actually iam making a futures trading robot and there is no OCO Option in futures as in Spot.So please help me.